# Detecting a PO Box (address) in a C# string

Tags: c#, string

I am working on a project where the users have to put in the physical address of their organization, in many cases users will put in a PO Box rather than their physical address.  I need a way in C# to determine whether or not a user put in a P.O. Box or PO Box (or any other variation of this) rather 29 Maple Street style address.  I have had a few thoughts, but I thought I would get some really great feedback here.

Thanks

Comment: "I have had a few thoughts": them put them in practice and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: did not get stuck, but the only idea I had was to have two if conditions with “PO Box” and “P.O. Box”, convert everything to lower case and see if a submitted string contained either of them.  I was thinking there must be a better solution than this, but was unsure what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to parse the address as a string. Then find a 'P.O. Box' or 'PO Box' in the array: if it finds it, the PO BOX should be the next element(s).
You will also need a way to detect the city so you know when to stop. You could use google's geonames (http://www.geonames.org/) as a data base.